# Prove that $1^{p-2}+2^{p-2}+ \dots +((p-1)/2)^{p-2}\equiv (2-2^p)/p$ mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Given an odd prime $p$ how can I prove that 
$$1^{p-2}+2^{p-2}+ \dots +\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^{p-2}\equiv \frac{2-2^p}{p} \pmod{p}$$

I wanted to prove that all the numbers are negative powers of 2, but I don't know if that is correct. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Take primes $p$ of the form $4k+1$, and see what you get. Take primes of the form $4k+3$ and see what you get. Use the fact that the number of terms is odd on the right side in one case, and even in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Prove $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k\pmod p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155685/prove-binomp-1k-equiv-1k-pmod-p), we have that
\begin{align*}2^p-2
&=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k}=p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k}\equiv p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\\
&=p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{-1}{2j}+p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{2j-1}\\
&=-p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{2j}+p\sum_{j'=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{p-2j'}\\
&\equiv-p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{2j}-p\sum_{j'=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{2j'}\\
\\&=-p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{1}{j}
\equiv-p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}j^{p-2}
\pmod{p^2}
\end{align*}
where in the last step we used the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Any further doubt?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to read it before. Let me a minute to understand it.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Fine, let me know your opinion.

Comment: Why you use the $k $'s such that $12\mid k $?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I separated even and odds. I edited my answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, now is totally clear. Thanks!